# Template toolkit compare dates

Tags: perl, if-statement, template-toolkit

In template toolkit I want to add some text based on whether the date of my item is in the past,future or today.
I am getting a field from the database called myDate
which is a date field which looks like the below.
myDate: 2012-12-12

In my template I am trying to do something like this.  But I can't get the template to run when I try.  Is there a way to do this in template toolkit?

```
    [% USE date %]
    [% IF myDate < date.format %]
    past
    [% IF myDate > date.format %]
    future
    [% ELSE %]
    today
    [% END %]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps comparing apples and orang-utans?

Is your myDate value a string or a DateTime object? Both sides of the expression need to be the same type, and DateTime does a lot of overloading so that you can compare DateTime objects using `>`, `<=` and so on. If one side of the expression is an object and the other is a string, you will run into problems.

Secondly, `date.format` without a formatting string returns the default POSIX representation, which according to [Template::Plugin::Date](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Date.html) is `'%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y'`, almost certainly not what you want.

So if myDate is a DateTime, try:

```
[% IF myDate < date.now %]
```

and if it's definitely a string, try:

```
[% IF myDate < date.format('%Y-%m-%d') %]
```

Hope that helps.

---

**UPDATE**

I was referring to perl DateTime objects, not whether the field in the database is date or datetime. Generally, database dates or datetimes are 'inflated' to perl DateTime objects by the ORM (DBIC or whatever.) You haven't told us enough about the provenance of `myDate` to know. I suggest you display `myDate` and `date.now` in your template to debug further, ie:

```
[%- "myDate = "; myDate; " date.now = "; date.now; "<br/>";
    myDate.strftime('I must be a DateTime object: %Y-%m-%d'); "<br/>";
    date.now.strftime('I must be a DateTime object: %Y-%m-%d'); "<br/>"; -%]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. it is a date field not a DateTime field. I get something to output now but if I do [% IF myDate < date.now %]a[% ELSE %]b[% END %] I only seem to get a if it is in the past or present?

Comment: I was writing a response - it got too long. See my updated answer.